# Help getting iPython to run from the OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-leopard, python

Got a heads up from stackoverflow.com to ask the question here.

I'm going through the matplotlib documentation and prepared to use the iPython interactive Python shell with `ipython -pylab`. However I get this:

```
MBP:~ Me$ ipython -pylab
-bash: ipython: command not found
```

Did I fail to install iPython? I used `easy_install` as advised.

Any ideas?

*Update*

Thought I'd just say that I found the iPython "executable" in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin` after doing a Spotlight search.

Still a little confused as to what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your Python 2.6 installation is through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), based on the `/opt/local` prefix. If you didn't install it with MacPorts and have your own reason for using `/opt/local`, ignore this answer. If you did, you can install ipython with `port`.

```
port install py26-ipython
```

Make sure that your `$PATH` environment variable is set to include `/opt/local/bin`. This should have been done by the MacPorts installer. My `~/.profile` looks like:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2009-03-05_at_21:11:52: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


# MacPorts Installer addition on 2009-03-05_at_21:11:52: adding an appropriate MANPATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
# Finished adapting your MANPATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

I would be careful using easy_install in conjunction with MacPorts python, especially for modules that MacPorts already provides. For example, MacPorts ipython puts the executable at `/opt/local/bin/ipython2.6` along with `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipython`

**EDIT**
To uninstall the easy_installed version of ipython, from what I know you'll need to manually delete the associated files. I'm taking a leap here based on my installation of ipython. First delete the executables:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipcluster
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipcontroller
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipengine
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/iptest
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipython
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipython-wx
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/ipythonx
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/irunner
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pycolor
```

Then, delete the folder and egg-info in site-packages:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/IPython/
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.10-py2.6.egg-info
```

Then, delete the doc folder:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/doc/ipython/
```

Then, delete the man files:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/ipcluster.1.gz
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/ipcontroller.1.gz
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/ipengine.1.gz
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/ipython-wx.1.gz
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/ipython.1.gz
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/ipythonx.1.gz
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/irunner.1.gz
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share/man/man1/pycolor.1.gz
```

Finally, open the file `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth` and see if there is a line referring to the ipython egg. Delete that.

Comment: Oh bugger, I think I may have done something noobish and indeed installed `iPython` using `easy_install`. A friend installed Python 2.6.4 installed using MacPorts around November. I think he set it up such that I can run Python off the terminal without digging deep into the `/opt/local/bin` - would that make sense that I can just type and run python in the Terminal because of that? Yes, I'm still very green at this Unix/Linux/MacOSX thing...

Comment: PS - How can I uninstall the `easy_install` version of `iPython`?

Comment: Many thanks :) That sorted out the stupid `easy_install` business. Then I tried to run `port -v selfupdate` followed by `sudo port install py26-ipython` and then I was flabbergasted as it tried to install `gettext` and `sqlite3` and then proceeded to upgrade my Python from 2.6.4 to 2.6.5...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with your PATH. Check your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc in Terminal and make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH before the Apple defaults.

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
```

More information here: http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/Py4Science/InstallationOSX